# SDK used to develop ARSoccer

Tags: augmented-reality

I'm looking to build my first AR application on the android platform. I have developed a couple of android apps, but nothing to do with graphics and much less with "Augmented Reality".
The ARSoccer app for the iPhone has some of the features that I wanted to use. I just not sure as to what sdk or library to use to track the foot movement against a virtual object. (in the case of ARSoccer the foot movement is being tracked against a virtual soccer ball).
Can anyone point me into what sdk/library to use?

I have taken a look at QCAR sdk by Qualcomm and Layar. But they do not seem to have what I want.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

These to differ greatly in AR techniques.
Layar uses location based AR while QCAR uses image recognition.
Take a look at QCAR because it's had a few updates since June.
https://ar.qualcomm.at/qdevnet/